# delete file on attached SD card reader IOS using maui

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin, maui

I have posted elsewhere on problems with Android trying to do this
I have a small circ app which tries to read log file on attached SD card reader. Processes the data, backs up to cloud - Then I want to clean log file from SD card reader
I am using VS 2022 and Maui  (c# not java or c++)
I have found it almost impossible in Android (>31) and no suggestions so I presume it is actually impossible in Maui code
BUT this below is peculiar
On IOS I can identify file (and presumably am able to delete it  (Android return false on File.Exists() but IOS returns true. Then after calling DisplayAlert() the File.Exists() returns false
That means I cannot use a DisplayAlert to confirm deletion

```
if (csvlen < 300)   // one line per second means 5 mins ignore
        {
            var ttt = File.Exists(csvorig);    // this call returns true
            var nl = System.Environment.NewLine;
            var answ = await DisplayAlert(dbpath + nl + "Small file", "the file you've selected contains no flightdata" + nl + "prob cause = switching on avionics for < 5min " + nl + " file should be deleted", "DELETE", "ignore");
            if (answ)
            {

                var ttt3 = File.Exists(csvorig);   // this call return false
```

As above before DisplayAlert the file is visible - after the call to DisplayAlert it is not and cannot be deleted

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be?

file visible before call to DisplayAlert - not visible after

Comment: We cannot read or write file directly from sd card. You may have heard of Application Sandbox. In iOS, an application is limited to reading and writing files within its home directory (installed location); it cannot access another application’s files.

Comment: Tx liquid shen. But by some miracle I am managing to do the delete. I am calling conditional code (Android/IOS)

Comment: I'll try to post the code which works when I'm back to office for the assistance of others

Comment: So glad that you solved it! You can post an answer which may help others with same issues.